# How to get previous state from NGXS store

Tags: ngxs, ngx-share

In NGXS we have getState() to get the current state. Is there a way to get the previous state from the store? I am looking for a solution to this as I have to implement Undo/Redo kind of functionality. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `store.snapshot()` method to get the snapshot of the store at that particular time. You can store the snapshot in a variable and then, in case of a re-roll, just use `store.reset()` with the snapshot.

```ts
export class MyComponent {

  private initialSnapshot: MyStoreStateModel;

  constructor(private store: Store){
    this.initialSnapshot = store.snapshot();
  }

  // ... component logic / state modification logic

  rollback = () => this.store.reset(this.initialSnapshot); 
}
```

Adjust to your needs...

Hope this helps a little :-)

Answer (score 2):

@Mark Whitfield is correct that there is no direct way to get the previous state with NGXS.
Using NGXS I had a use case where I wanted to know the previous value to perform an undo-style operation.

I used the regular NGXS `@Selector` syntax to tap into the state slice I was interested in, then in I subscribed directly to that `Observable` and used the rxjs [pairwise](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/pairwise.html) operator to give me the new emitted value and the previous value. Worked well for the way I wanted to consume those values so it might fit what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get the previous state by default, but you can definitely create a service that monitors the state and pushes a copy into its own stack.
You can then restore this state using the `reset` method on the store.

You would probably use the `select` and `reset` methods of the `store`. See here for more info: https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/concepts/store#selecting-state

Answer (score -1):

You can use "redux-undo" from npm to implement undo and redo. It is pretty simple and straight forward. 
You can find the docs [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/implementing-undo-history)